# it doesn't work anymore when dependencies are injected in angular.module("myApp",[])

Tags: angularjs

I'm going to develop a mean project and when i create a new `angular module`, and it into the array of `root module`, it doesn't work any more? can you guys know why?
codes below:

```
angular.module('userApp', ['ngAnimate', 'app.routes', 
        'authService', 'mainCtrl', 'userCtrl', 'userService','videoCtrl'])
            .config(function($httpProvider) {
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');    
});
```

`videoCtrl` is a `new module` that i wanna add, thank you for answering!!

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: What does your console.log tell you? What error? Are the injectables `videoCtrl` - and the others - Angular modules? Or module controllers?

Comment: the error is when i add the new module "videoCtrl", data doesn't show in the page. angular.module("videoCtrl",['videoService'])
    .controller("videoController",function($http,Video){
        var vm=this;
        
        vm.test="hello world"
        alert("hello world");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm shotgunning it a bit here, but it seems as if you're attempting to call every controller/service as a dependency. That is extremely insufficient and you don't need to do that. You could do it like this instead.

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ng-route','myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services']).config(function(){});
```

And within controllers.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('mainCtrl', function(){}).controller('videoCtrl', function(){})
```

Make sure in your dom you include angular first, then controllersjs or services js. You want to keep things as simple as possible to prevent bugs.

Comment: thank you, i fixed the problem, cause i didn't add the controllerjs and service into the page. And i think it is proper to organize the files as you mentioned. I will do it later